# python twisted json decoding

Tags: python, json, twisted

I've got a following code developed using python twisted library:

```
class Cache(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        request = json.loads(data)
        self.factory.handle[request['command']](**request)
        self.transport.write(data)

class CacheFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Cache(self)
    def handle_get(self, **kwargs):
        print 'get\n', kwargs
    def handle_set(self, **kwargs):
        print 'set\n', kwargs
    def handle_delete(self, **kwargs):
        print 'delete\n', kwargs
    handle = {
        'get': handle_get,
        'set': handle_set,
        'delete': handle_delete,
    }

reactor.listenTCP(int(sys.argv[1]), CacheFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I run a client connection using telnet:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
{"command": "set", "value": 1234567890}
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

an exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 146, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 460, in doRead
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "./server.py", line 18, in dataReceived
    self.factory.handle[request['command']](**request)
exceptions.TypeError: handle_set() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

which I don't understand. There could be something wrong with line `self.factory.handle[request['command']](**request)`, but in my opinion it's correct - it passes the `self` parameter implicitly (it's a method afterall) and unpacked request parameter explicitly. The exception message says the function takes 1 argument, and it's a lie :) because it takes 2 parameters: `self, **kwargs`. And it's not true that I pass 0 arguments, since I pass 2.

Can someone help me to spot the problem?

---

in case it helps, the json request is decoded into:

```
{u'command': u'set', u'value': 1234567890}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is now, the `handle_*` methods are instance methods, yet the `handle` dict points to **unbound** methods. That is, `self` is not being passed implicitly. Try this instead:

```
class CacheFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Cache(self)
    def handle_get(self, **kwargs):
        print 'get\n', kwargs
    def handle_set(self, **kwargs):
        print 'set\n', kwargs
    def handle_delete(self, **kwargs):
        print 'delete\n', kwargs
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        protocol.Factory.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.handle = {
            'get': self.handle_get,
            'set': self.handle_set,
            'delete': self.handle_delete,
        }
```

Alternatively, you could keep your `handle` the same and do this:

```
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        request = json.loads(data)
        self.factory.handle[request['command']](self.factory, **request)
        self.transport.write(data)
```

Or, you could take this approach and then you don't need a `handle` dict either way:

```
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        request = json.loads(data)
        getattr(self.factory, "handle_%s" % (request['command'],))(**request)
        self.transport.write(data)
```

Also note your `dataReceived`, as it is now, is unsafe, because packets might get split up arbitrarily - that is, you might not receive an entire `json` message in one shot.

Comment: wow, thanks for exclusive explanation. What would you do to ensafe dataReceived method in case of json format?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Check out the [Twisted FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith). Basically you have to keep a buffer of all the data you received, and your protocol has to be such that you know when you've received a full message. In your case you could do it by trying to parse the buffer and seeing if it fails, I guess, but it's probably better to pass along some sort of length info, e.g. the first 4 bytes could be a `uint32` in network-byte-order of the size of the message.

Comment: Thank you very much! PS I like the handler_map-less solution the best

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: no probs! Yea I like that method the best too, that's the way I've done and seen others do it in the past. You should add some error checking to get nice errors in case a command doesn't exist though.